# How do I know when a child process died in python3 on windows platform?

Tags: python, process, synchronization, subprocess

In linux I use   **subprocess.Popen**   to create a child process, and define a signal handler for   **SIGCHLD**.   When the child process died, parent process recieves   **SIGCHLD**   signal and the handler will do sth.

But on Windows there's no   **SIGCHLD**   signal, how can I know when the child process exited?

Comment: You can learn that using `tasklist`  or by communicating with the sub-process.

Comment: @dsgdfg The child process may cost a long time before exited, so I need a non-blocking method. If using communicate(), my main process will be blocked...

Comment: **No Method - Let me go**  Because Windows and Linux kernel work differently,It does not automatically create the Windows application tree (in third-party software). To do this, you must use an API or additional application. why do you want to follow the application  you already left to alone ? Write into another thread and change a variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify with TASKLIST FI(Filter) method that a given pid exist or not.
so the idea is

1) Generate a process.pid

2) See the status of PID with TASK list filter function

e.g.

TASKLIST /FI "PID eq 6228"

3) Kill the pid

4) see the status of pid again, it should not exist

below is the code, which will do the same

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import subprocess


command='cmd /K '

#This will open a new command prompt window 
p1=Popen(command,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

#printing the pid value
print p1.pid


# created a function to  Verify if the pid exist
def check_pid():
    command1="TASKLIST /FI "+ '"PID eq '+ str(p1.pid)+'"'
    p2=Popen(command1,stdout=PIPE)
    out=p2.communicate()[0]
    print out


#Kill the pid 
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID %i' % p1.pid)

#wait for some time and see if the pid exist

import time
time.sleep(3)

check_pid()
```